Cursor always go back to position 0 in one of my controllers from a ListView.Builder
I hope you can help me, i've been doing everything but nothing works for me, I have a ListView Builder widget, that lets me add any items I want, each item has 3 fields, one of them is giving me trouble, everytime i type something in hoursController, the cursor goes to the position 0, so is uncomfortable to type, as it should be a numeric value. Here I add part of my code:
void updateTotalHours() {
    int newTotal = 0;
    for (var project in projects) {
      if (project['hours'] != null && project['hours'].isNotEmpty) {
        newTotal += int.parse(project['hours']);
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      totalHours = newTotal;
    });
  }

Here's where I call the widget:
ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: projects.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return buildProjectItem(index);
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    projects.add({});
                  });
                },
                child: Text('AGREGAR ACTIVIDAD'),
              ),

Widget buildProjectItem(int index) {
    TextEditingController projectController = TextEditingController(text: projects[index]['projectName'] ?? '');
    TextEditingController activityController = TextEditingController(text: projects[index]['activityName'] ?? '');
    TextEditingController hoursController = TextEditingController(text: projects[index]['hours'] ?? '');

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TypeAheadFormField<Parametro>(
                textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                  controller: projectController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'PROYECTO',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 12.0),
                  ),
                ),
                suggestionsCallback: getSugProjects,
                onSuggestionSelected: (project) {
                  setState(() {
                    projects[index]['project'] = project.id;
                    projects[index]['projectName'] = project.name;
                    projectController.text = project.name;
                  });
                },
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                validator: (proyecto) {
                  if (proyecto!.isEmpty || !projectsList.any((project) => project.name == proyecto)) {
                    return 'SELECCIONE UN PROYECTO DE LA LISTA';
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, project) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(project.name),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Expanded(
              child: TypeAheadFormField<Parametro>(
                textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                  controller: activityController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'ACTIVIDAD',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 12.0),
                  ),
                ),
                suggestionsCallback: getSugActivities,
                onSuggestionSelected: (activity) {
                  setState(() {
                    projects[index]['activity'] = activity.id;
                    projects[index]['activityName'] = activity.name;
                    activityController.text = activity.name;
                  });
                },
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                validator: (activity) {
                  if (activity!.isEmpty || !activitiesList.any((act) => act.name == activity)) {
                    return 'SELECCIONE UNA ACTIVIDAD DE LA LISTA';
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, activity) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(activity.name),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: hoursController,
                readOnly: false,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                ],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'HORAS DEDICADAS',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 12.0),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    projects[index]['hours'] = value;
                    updateTotalHours();
                    hoursController.value = TextEditingValue(
                      text: value,
                      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: value.length),
                    );
                  });
                  
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  projects.removeAt(index);
                  updateTotalHours();
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline, color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Divider(),
      ],
    );
  }

I have tried using selection property, collapsed, saving the position, but nothing worked for me. And I expect my field to have a normal behavior, so I can move the cursor freely and it stays in the last position i left it
